# NDde.DdeException: The client failed to request "Firefox|WWW_GetWindowInfo!URL"

Tags: c#, winforms, url, firefox, ndde

I am getting an error please help me

```
using NDde.Client;
```

My error:

> NDde.DdeException: The client failed to request
>   "Firefox|WWW_GetWindowInfo!URL". ---> NDde.Foundation.DdemlException:
>   The client failed to request "Firefox|WWW_GetWindowInfo!URL".

**visual studio 2008 f 3.5 , x86**

**tested on Firefox 49.0** 
**API from http://ndde.codeplex.com/**

**Referral Code block**

```
public string GetUrl(string browser){
  DdeClient dde = new DdeClient(browser, "WWW_GetWindowInfo");
  dde.Connect();
  string url = dde.Request("URL", int.MaxValue);
  string[] text = url.Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  dde.Disconnect();
  return text[0].Substring(1);
}
```

Comment: this code block works for old firefox version.. but when firefox update to 49.0 it is not working... plz help me

Comment: I ran across the same problem. Still looking for a fix.

Comment: @AkshayKamble Got solution? or any alternative?